# Crash looking for a custom view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

1. I created a UIView called FollowUp
2. I created an .xib file and attached it to this class
3. In the FollowUp class I implemented the start methods
4. In my storyboard I added a view and defined it as an extension of a FollowUp

Now when I try to run the app to display the view the app breaks as in the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my start code.:

```
import UIKit

class FollowUp: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FollowUp", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
        contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you use `commonInit` / for what?

Comment: Could be a view lifecycle issue...I propose a trial: 1. remove the call to commonInit from the init methods, 2. rename commonInit to "addToViewController(vc: ViewController), only adding a line for vc.view.addSubView, 3. in the view controller's viewDidLoadMethod, create the view and call addToViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first image, the custom class should be on the File's Owner, not the view.